# Search stops working when adding a second filter query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

I'm hoping you can help me with an issue I'm having. I'm new to ElasticSearch and am currently trying to implement a log search method that's going to be filtering through large amounts of logs. Currently, I can make it filter based on selected log types and that works fine, but as soon as I add the second filter, it no longer returns any results.

The only difference between the two filters I've added so far is, one is an int array, the other is a string list as seen in the current code, I've also tried converting it to a string array but to no help.

```
    [Route("logs/search")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int[] logTypes, int entityType, string entitySource)
    {
        using (var db = new mtaEntities())
        {
            var targetSources = new List<string>();
            switch (entityType)
            {
                // Username/charactername
                case 0:
                    var characters = db.characters.Where(i => i.charactername.ToLower().Replace("_", " ") == entitySource.ToLower()).ToList();
                    accounts user = null;
                    if (characters.Any())
                    {
                        var accountId = characters.FirstOrDefault().account;
                        if (accountId != null)
                        {
                            user = db.accounts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == accountId);
                            characters.AddRange(db.characters.Where(i => i.account == user.id));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user = db.accounts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.username.ToLower() == entitySource.ToLower());
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            characters.AddRange(db.characters.Where(i => i.account == user.id).ToList());
                        }
                    }
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        targetSources.Add("AC-" + user.id);
                        foreach (var item in characters)
                        {
                            targetSources.Add("CH-" + item.id);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            var filters = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Log>, QueryContainer>>();
            filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(te => te.Field(fi => fi.LogType).Terms(logTypes)));
            filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(te => te.Field(fi => fi.SourceUser).Terms(targetSources)));
            var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<Log>();
            searchDescriptor.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Filter(filters)));
            var query = ElasticClient.Search<Log>(searchDescriptor);
            var results = query.Documents;
            return View(new Logs
            {
                IndexLastRebuilt = db.settings.FirstOrDefault(i => i.name == "elasticIndexLastRebuilt").value,
                LogResults = results.ToList(),
                LogTypes = db.logtypes.ToList()
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say `"it stops working."`, do you mean that it doesn't return you the results that you're expecting? the filters will be `AND`ed together. Since the second filter only contains a single term to match, I think it should be a `Term(...)` query as opposed to a `Terms(...)` query

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't return any results - I've updated my question. I'll try out using a single Term later and see if it helps out

Comment: filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(te => te.Field(fi => fi.SourceUser).Terms("AC-1"))); - if you change either of the "Terms" to "Term" the other can't be a Term or a Terms.

Comment: the value supplied to a `.Term()` query is through `.Value()` (as opposed to `.Terms()` on a .`Terms()` query): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/term-query-usage.html

Comment: Ahh, right. I think that would work. It seems I left out an essential part of my question. Please review the code again, the "AC-1" that was previous there, was an attempt to see if it would get anything from that. It's really meant to get all results where targetSources contains the value of SourceUser

Comment: Could you add your mapping for the `Log` in the idnex you're targeting, and capture the request you're sending with `OnRequestCompleted` (also set `.DisableDirectStreaming()`): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-on-request-completed.html